# When Running App in Simulator Xcode Gets Pushed to a Background Window

Tags: xcode, macos, simulator

Whenever I build and run just this one particular app  in XCode, the UI window of XCode gets pushed back underneath all existing running windows on OSX ( behind the browser and textedit etc...). This means I can't see the Xcode console debug outputs while playing with the app in the simulator. I feel like this could just be a quick setting in xcode or osx but I'm not sure why and how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Use [*Spaces*](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11158) and develop with Xcode in its own virtual window.  You will have just Xcode and Simulator wrestling for screen space then.

I normally have at least 5 windows open in *Spaces*:

1. Mail and Skype.
2. Web Browser
3. Xcode
4. Terminal/Finder/Odds and sods
5. Spare

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to switch windows.

Comment: thats good advice to circumvent the issue, but that doesnt explain how to fix the issue of xcode droppping to the background.